# Will many attributes use (much) more memory in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, memory-leaks

As a Ruby on Rails-programmer I am constantly struggling with memory problems and my apps on Heroku often hit the 100% mark. As I have learned RoR by learning-by-doing and mostly by myself I believe I have missed quite a lot of conventions and best practises in terms of, specifically, memory conservation.

Measuring memory usage is difficult, even using great gems as `derailed` as it will only give me very indirect pointers to code that will use too much memory.

I tend to use a lot of gems and a lot of attributes on my major models. My most important one, my Product model, holds some 40 attributes and there are about 400.000 objects in my database. Which brings me to my question, or rather clarifications.

A. I assume that if I do a `Product.all` request in the controller it will load some (400.000*40 = ) 16M "fields" (not sure what to call it) into memory, right?

B. If I do `Product.where(<query that brings up half of the objects>)` will load 200.000*40= 8M "fields" into memory, right?

C. If I do `Product.select(:id,:name, :price)` would bring 400.000*3= 1.2M "fields" into memory, right?

D. I also assume that if I do selections of attributes that are integers (such as price) it will be less expensive than strings (such as name) which in term will be less expensive than text (such as description). In other word a `Product.select(:id)` will use less memory than `Product.select(:long_description_with_1000_characters)`, right?

E. I also assume that if I do a search such as `Product.all.limit(30)`, it will use less memory than a `Product.all.limit(500)`, right?

F. Considering all this, and assuming the answer is YES on all of the above I assume it would be worth the time to go through my code to find "fat and greedy" requests of the 16M type. In that case, what would be the most effective way, or tool, of understanding how many "fields" a certain request will use? At the moment, I think I will just go through the code and try to picture, and trouble shoot, each database request to see if it can be slimmed down.

Edit: Another way of phrasing the (F) question: If I do a change to a certain database-request. How can I tell if it is using less memory, or not? My current approach is to upload to Heroku on my production app and check the total memory usage, which is VERY blunt obviously.

FYI: I am using Scout on Heroku to find memory bloats which is useful to some extent. I also use `bullet` gem to find N+1 issues, which helps to speed up requests but I am not sure if it affects memory issues.

Any pointers to blog posts or similar that discuss this would be interesting as well. In addition, any comments on how to make sure requests like the above will not bloat or use too much memory would be highly appreciated.

Comment: IMHO all your assumptions are correct. But it feels to me like you miss the most obvious answer to how to keep the memory consumption low: _Do not load all records into memory at the same time._ Use pagination in views and if you need to iterate through all records use `find_each` or `find_in_batches` instead of `all.each`.

Comment: I agree with @spickermann. It doesn't make sense to load 400k objects because on server side it will consume a lot of memory and client's browser will just stuck trying to render all these objects. Also you could use `Product.pluck(:id)` because it will return a plain Array rather not array of ActiveRecord objects

Comment: Thanks, and I know. I could have made it more clear that I have simplified my question in order to make the point of the question be more clear. I do not load all those products into view! I heavily use pluck and find_each, this is merely to be certain of some principles so I know how to trouble shoot.